# App Crash When using actionBar.setTitle();

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-sqlite, title

i have a multiple  list view and i fetch all the datas from Sqlite to each list view

Now i want to change the Second list view Action bar Name into the first list view selection Title  Name

when i select any one item(Title Name)  pass that using intent to next activity and i set the Action bar but my app was crash 
Here is the Code

My First List View Code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
  dbHelper = new SqlLiteDbHelper(this);
        try {
            dbHelper.openDataBase();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        sqLiteDatabase = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = dbHelper.gettitles(sqLiteDatabase);
        String[] from = new String[]{dbHelper.TITLE};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.title};
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.title_row, cursor, from, to);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                cursor = (Cursor) (listView.getItemAtPosition(position));
                String selectedItem = cursor.getString(0);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SubcategoryActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("selectedItem", selectedItem);
                startActivity(intent);
```

My Second List view Code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.subcategory_activity);

        ActionBar actionBar=getActionBar();
 listView2= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
        Intent intent= getIntent();
        final String selectedData = intent.getStringExtra("selectedItem");
        actionBar.setTitle(selectedData);
        dbHelper = new SqlLiteDbHelper(this);
        try {
            dbHelper.openDataBase();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        sqLiteDatabase=dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor=dbHelper.getsubcategory(sqLiteDatabase,selectedData);
        String[] from = new String[] { dbHelper.SUBCATEGORY };
        int[] to = new int[] {R.id.subcategory };
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.subcategory_row,cursor,from,to);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listView2.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Logcat

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ky.sidd/com.example.ky.sidd.SubcategoryActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.ky.sidd.SubcategoryActivity.onCreate(SubcategoryActivity.java:60)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5326)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2218)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Actionbar actionbar = getActionbar();

or

Actionbar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();

actionbar.setTitle("your title goes here.");
```

Comment: Thanks But i want to set title in actionbar based on the selected datas from sqlite

Comment: when you select any one item like double cheeze pass this using intent to next activity where you want to settitle.

Comment: Check the Updated Code @akhil

Comment: try this. getIntent().getExtras().getString("selectedItem");

Comment: And check selectedItem is null or not in first listview

Comment: getIntent().getExtras().getString("selectedItem"); i try this line but still same problem

Comment: please check you have value in selectedItem in first activity

Comment: how to check that plz Help?

Comment: App was Working Perfect Before Add  actionBar.setTitle(selectedData);

Comment: String selectedItem = cursor.getString(0); if(!selectedItem.equals("")){}

Comment: IN First listview or in second listview??

Comment: if app is crashed try getSupportActionBar().setTitle().

Comment: When i try getSupportActionBar().setTitle() it shows Error so only i try ActionBar actionBar=getActionBar();

Comment: On first activity in onItemclicked of listview

Comment: String selectedItem = cursor.getString(0); if(!selectedItem.equals("")){} check this in your first activity. i think selectedItem does not have any value.

Comment: 'String selectedItem = cursor.getString(0);
                    if(!selectedItem.equals(""))
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SubcategoryActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("selectedItem", selectedItem);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }' i tryed this but still error

Comment: startActivity(intent);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),selectedItem,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); it still show the same problem

Comment: Debug your App and see the selectedItem have some value after String selectedItem = cursor.getString(0); if slectedItem is null then thats the problem

Comment: i just use  Log.e("SELECTED",selectedItem); it shows the data in debug as E/SELECTED﹕ GENERAL

Answer (score 0):

Search about `getActionbar.setTitle("")` or `getSupportActionbar.setTitle("");`

Comment: Check My Updated Code @emmgfx

Answer (score 0):

```
getActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ff0000'>ActionBartitle Name </font>"));
```

**Change *getActionBar()* to *getSupportActionBar()* if you are using the support library for ActionBar.**

Answer (score 0):

Very first check if your selectedData string and action-bar null or not because you got null-pointer exception

You can use Toolbar. and set the toolbar as actionbar.
In toolbar add textview.

```
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
textView.settext("your list name");
```

for ref use [link](http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-app.html)

Comment: how to add Toolbar with Textview??

Comment: i have a custom listview right to i want to write toolbar code in my custom layout right?

Comment: use above link for ref